# CSS breaking with _renderItem in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm facing some problem with _renderItem in jquery autocomplete.

I have a autocomplete fiddle (not using _renderItem) - https://jsfiddle.net/fuyfksLd/

```
This code has a different CSS than usual
```

I've added some CSS which is breaking when I add the _renderItem code - https://jsfiddle.net/fjwbLnhv/ .

```
The background of the list items shrinks.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: not able to replicate the defect

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    add in css


   .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a{
   text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the content of the `<li>` inside a div not an anchor e.g.:

```
<div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">ActionScript</div>
```

They use different styling.